# Make AJAX call more secure

Tags: php, ajax

I did this script for a project of mine, but I would like to void users to inspect elements and change some values here, like ID and page to redirect.
There is a way to do it without make lots of protection in server side?

```
window.setInterval(function(){
var dataString = 'id='+<?=$userDetails->id;?>;
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url: 'game2.php',
    success:function(data) {
    }
});
}, 6000);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Simply no on client side;

Comment: There is no way to prevent users from modifying client side code. You will have to make sure that the server side has water proof security!

Comment: Use a token to identifiy users. Require authentication to get a token. Check authenticated user permissions for all actions. Use a SSL connection. It requires server-side securities.

Comment: You can pass encrypted data using encryption algorithms.

Comment: Great! Thank you all.